# Grabbing dragged and dropped items as child nodes of <div>

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I am developing a website where users drag and drop some items into boxes. The boxes are represented as div elements. In the end I am running this javascript function to return a string for each div element to see which items (children) are dragged into.

```
function get_children_string(div_id) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(div_id);
    var child_str = div_id;
    var i = 0;
    for(i=0;i<elem.childNodes.length;i++)
        child_str = child_str + elem.childNodes[i].id;
    return child_str;
}
```

For example, if three items with id's s1, s4, s6 are dragged into a div with id d1:

```
get_children_string('d1') // returns 'd1s1s4s6'
```

The problem is whenever I drag more than 5 items, some children get lost. For example, I drag and drop 7 items, and I am getting a result with 4 child nodes. Or I drag 6 items, and get 3 child nodes. I made sure that all child id's are fine (I mean not empty strings), and actually every time I am getting elem.childNodes.length 3 or 4.

What am I doing wrong here? Can anybody suggest a better way to handle this?

Comment: post the html code as well, how and where the divs are being created

Comment: @AbdulJabbar I am using some php functions/classes to build my html code. And it will be super hard to create the html code out of that. Sorry about that.

Comment: hmm one reason for your problem can be that all the divs are not created yet when your this part of the code runs? are they all created and you cna access their ids?

Comment: Yes this code runs after a button labeled "Save" is clicked. And at that point already everything is created and visible on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty hard to point out the problem from the part of the code you've written here. You need to check if all the child divs are actually being added to the parent div or not. If they are there, then the following simple code should work fine for you:

HTML:

```
<div id="d1">
    <div id="s1"></div>
    <div id="s2"></div>
    <div id="s3"></div>
    <div id="s4"></div>
    <div id="s5"></div>
    <div id="s6"></div>
    <div id="s7"></div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
function get_children_string(div_id) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(div_id);
    var child_str = div_id;
    var i = 0;

    var childNodes = elem.childNodes;
    for(i=0;i<elem.childNodes.length;i++) {
        if(elem.childNodes[i].nodeType !=3) //because it includes some whitespace and other garbage nodes
            child_str = child_str + elem.childNodes[i].id;
    }
    return child_str;
}

alert(get_children_string('d1')); //gives d1s1s2s3s4s5s6s7
```

**[See the DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/5vesotfm/)**

Comment: Thanks for the example. I am also making this work where there is no drag and drop involved. It looks like drag and drop somehow does not work as expected. Will check a little more.

Comment: best of luck for that and just remember console.log() or alert() are your best friends for that

Comment: I figured out the problem. The dropped items were becoming the children of previously dropped items. So when I check the grandchildren things are fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like selected elements () are not reaching a drop-zone.  Can you confirm mouse position vs  clones must intersect the target?  Alternatively, set an active class on the clicked items and go fetch them in the drop-zone success function.